# Load 3rd party page inside your page and USE it

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Is there a way to load whole new URL / page inside my site element so that you **can interact with that page without refreshing my page**? It's not a problem if it initially has to load with page refresh.

- jQuery.load()?
- jQuery.ajax()?

All I could find online was loading parts of your own site and there was no info about *using that loaded page without refresing your own page*. Example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dynamic").load("single.php");
});
```

I've previously loaded new pages inside modal but I need it inside div or anything else without "overlay".

Comment: what did you mean by interact ?

Comment: Random 3rd party page that you can use like normal without refreshing my page - press links, change pages, submit forms etc. Im not sure if that's possible, that's why Im asking. Cheers!

Comment: Possible guidance here: [Ajax/jQuery - Load webpage content into a div on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963799/ajax-jquery-load-webpage-content-into-a-div-on-page-load)

Comment: and here: [How do I load a webpage inside a div using Javascript without IFRAME and JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211969/how-do-i-load-a-webpage-inside-a-div-using-javascript-without-iframe-and-jquery)

Comment: and here: [How to load an external webpage into a div of a html page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145273/how-to-load-an-external-webpage-into-a-div-of-a-html-page)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Lots of reading to do. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are trying to **inject content from another domain**.
that means you want a part of your page load another domains content.

this **[page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax)** demonstrates the issue very clearly. **[take a look there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax)** and read the answers carefully.